# Append! in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, append

I'm learning R5RS Scheme at the moment (from PocketScheme) and I find that I could use a function that is built into some variants of Scheme but not all: Append!

In other words - destructively changing a list.

I am not so much interested in the actual code as an answer as much as understanding the process by which one could pass a list as a function (or a vector or string) and then mutate it.

example:

```
(define (append! lst var)
    (cons (lst var))
)
```

When I use the approach as above, I have to do something like `(define list (append! foo (bar))` which I would like something more generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutation, though allowed, is strongly discouraged in Scheme. PLT even went so far as to remove `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` (though they "replaced" them with `set-mcar!` and `set-mcdr!`). However, a spec for `append!` appeared in [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#append!). This `append!` is a little different than yours. In the SRFI, the implementation *may*, but is not *required* to modify the cons cells to append the lists.

If you want to have an `append!` that is *guaranteed* to change the structure of the list that's being appended to, you'll probably have to write it yourself. It's not hard:

```
(define (my-append! a b)
  (if (null? (cdr a))
      (set-cdr! a b)
      (my-append! (cdr a) b)))
```

To keep the definition simple, there is no error checking here, but it's clear that you will need to pass in a list of length at least 1 as `a`, and (preferably) a list (of any length) as `b`. The reason `a` must be at least length 1 is because you can't `set-cdr!` on an empty list.

Since you're interested in how this works, I'll see if I can explain. Basically, what we want to do is go down the list `a` until we get to the last `cons` pair, which is `(<last element> . null)`. So we first see if `a` is already the last element in the list by checking for `null` in the `cdr`. If it is, we use `set-cdr!` to set it to the list we're appending, and we're done. If not, we have to call `my-append!` on the `cdr` of `a`. Each time we do this we get closer to the end of `a`. Since this is a mutation operation, we're not going to return anything, so we don't need to worry about forming our modified list as the return value.

Comment: Follow up question - if mutation is strongly discouraged then what is best practices for a pattern like "building a list from a wizard dialog" ?

Coming from a Ruby background, this is something that I've been struggling with understanding..the mindset moreso than just the actual code to solve the problem.

Comment: In functional programming, whenever you want to change a data structure or somesuch, you pass it into a function and get back the modified data structure as the return. However the 'original' structure is left intact and what you're given is a new, altered copy (so to speak).

Comment: There is no "full guarantee" possible, which is exactly the problem with destructive functions -- if the list was empty, then no version of `append!` will ever be able to modify it.

Comment: I thought only empty list literals `'()` are immutable, but when they are constructed as in `(list)` then they are mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never for putting in a couple 2-3 cents on this topic...

(1) There's nothing wrong with using the destructive procedures in Scheme *while* there is a single reference to the stucture being modified. So for example, building a large list efficiently, piecemeal via a single reference - and when complete, making that (now presumably not-to-be-modified) list known and referred to from various referents.

(2) I think APPEND! should behave like APPEND, only (potentially) destructively. And so APPEND! should expect any number of lists as arguments. Each list but the last would presumably be SET-CDR!'d to the next.

(3) The above definition of APPEND! is essentially NCONC from Mac Lisp and Common Lisp. (And other lisps).