# Scheme Creating list

Tags: list, dictionary, scheme

Hello here is my Question.

I want to create 2 sub lists from the original list as follows

```
OriginalL '( (item1)(item2)(item3)(node1)(node2)(item4) ) ;its a list of lists
```

Lists i want to create

```
itemL '((item1)(item2)(item3)(item4))    ;only contains item type  
nodeL '((node1)(node2))   ;only contains node type
```

Here is my function that is not working correctly

```
(define itemL null)   

(define nodeL null)  

(define (separate OriginalL)  
   (map (lambda (i)  
          (if (item? i)
              (cons itemL i)
              (cons nodeL i))
        OrignalL))
```

But for some reason i cant get the list as i want. what is the problem. *item?* just returns #t or #f based on item type in original list.
Thanks

Comment: Please consider reformatting your code to make it more readable by using the editing tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to solve your problem:

```
(define itemL (filter item? OriginalL))
(define nodeL (filter (compose not item?) OriginalL))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `separate` to have the side effect of populating both of your global lists. In this case, you can use `append!` to add data to them as the original list is processed:

```
(define itemL '())   
(define nodeL '())  
(define (separate OriginalL)  
   (map (lambda (i)  
     (if (item? i)
         (append! itemL i)
         (append! nodeL i))
    OrignalL))
```

---

If the Scheme that you are using does not support `append!` you can write it yourself. For example, see: [Append! in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080328/append-in-scheme)

Comment: Dont you mean `append!` in that case?

Comment: yes that is what i want to do.  But it still gives empty list for itemL and nodeL. After separate. have you tested this code?

Comment: @user1233092: Your scheme might support `append!`. Try it, else write it :) It is a trivial proc.

Comment: I should mention i am using racket, **#lang racket** . From the link about implementing our on append, i cant use *set-cdr!* kinda stuck

Comment: Hmm... alternatively you could try just restructuring the code along the lines of `(set! itemL (append itemL i))`. Unfortunately I don't have a racket environment handy at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using R6RS, you can just do the following:

```
(let-values (((a b) (partition item? OriginalL))
  (set! itemL a)
  (set! nodeL b))
```

Many other scheme's will support the same. Perhaps look into SRFI1 support.